# using mysqli in phpexcel

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel

me trying to use mysqli in phpexcel, sadly it wouldnt work after i change to mysqli.

i tried to take data from vw_rekonsiliasi then export it to excel with phpexcel, sadly i still new using mysqli so error show at line

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
```

heres's the code

```
require_once "connection.php";
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";

// Create your database query
$query = "SELECT * FROM vw_rekonsiliasi";  

// Execute the database query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());

// Instantiate a new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
// Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
// Initialise the Excel row number
$rowCount = 1; 
// Iterate through each result from the SQL query in turn
// We fetch each database result row into $row in turn
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){ 
    // Set cell An to the "name" column from the database (assuming you have a column called name)
    //    where n is the Excel row number (ie cell A1 in the first row)
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['PO Number']); 
    // Set cell Bn to the "age" column from the database (assuming you have a column called age)
    //    where n is the Excel row number (ie cell A1 in the first row)
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['PO Date']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['Customer Name']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['Description']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $row['Qty PO']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount, $row['Total Qty SPB']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $row['Ots PO']); 
    // Increment the Excel row counter
    $rowCount++; 
} 

// Instantiate a Writer to create an OfficeOpenXML Excel .xlsx file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
// Write the Excel file to filename some_excel_file.xlsx in the current directory
$objWriter->save('rekonsiliasi_POvSPB.xlsx'); 

?>
```

Comment: what kind of error you get?

Comment: Perhaps you'd care to share with us what the error actually says.... error messages are actually designed to be helpful, and not letting us know what the error says is like asking us to help with one of our eyes closed

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using `MYSQLI_BOTH` when you're only using the result associatively? Why not use `MYSQLI_ASSOC`?

Comment: the kind of error is, phpexcel succedd create xlsx file but when i try to open that file error box shows up tell me that file is broken (still success open tho) and the data is empty

Comment: You say `error show at line

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){`.... that's completely different to the resultant file being broken..... so are you getting an error at that line? Or not?